# java.util.logging stops working after a while

Tags: java, logging, java.util.logging

I have a problem with java.util.logging. Everything is working just fine from the start but after a while the logger simply stops do write any data to file and I have no idea why (no exception, no error) nor how to find a cause of this problem.

I tried google but did not find any similar problem.

**tl,dr;**
java.util.logging stops working, want to know why.

Comment: Are you sure that the `Handler` being used isn't set to have a maximum size to the file?

Comment: is the thread stuck? or the code is happily running?

Comment: @Darien logger stops at (seemingly) random points in time/file size

Comment: @Jochen Bedersdorfer the whole app is running just fine (well, to be honest there is a lot of threads there) and the only problem is that at some point the logger (which was working ok in that environment) just stops outputting data to file.

Comment: can you report from jstack shows?

Answer (score 5):

Do note that loggers returned from the getLogger factory methods can be garbage collected at any time, and this can break things, like any levels you may have set in main().

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html

Use a strong reference to the Logger to avoid it to be garbaged:

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("");
```

Comment: Fantastic answer. Saved me many hours more work. Many, many thanks Scott

Comment: I'll second that. I'd been struggling with the same issue (i.e the logger ceasing to work after some time) for a whole 2 days!! Your answer solved the problem; I was not aware that the factory implicitly uses weak references.

Answer (score 0):

As @Darien comments, this could be a due to the [`FileHandler`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html) being configured with a non-zero `limit`.

- The handler could have switched to the next file - if `count` is greater that 1.
- If the `count` is equal to one, it could just stop.

---

FWIW - most Java developers gave up using java.util.logging many years ago.  I'd recommend log4j, slf4j or logback in preference to java.util.logging.

Comment: well, if there is no default value then no: `FileHandler fileMy = new FileHandler("logger.txt", true);`

Comment: Are you rendering that moot by using LogManager configuration properties?

Comment: @Stephen, We do use java.util.logging with improved Logger (no sync) and LogRecord (also no sync in the c-toe), never had issues. The framework is extensible and flexible enough. We have our own configurator with dynamic redeployable xml (i.e. dont use prop files), . Imo, it's superior to both frameworks, esp slf4j.

Comment: @bestsss - the problem is that you pretty much *have to* extend it.  For instance the standard configurator is just too limited (I found).  By contrast log4j and friends don't need to be extended to make them usable.

Comment: @Stephen, well prop files suck for anything besides beside key=value stuff (having dots and classes means bad props use), although JBuilder used to use props for configuration. I remember we embraced java.util.logging quite long ago (1.4 was new) but it's a standard lib and it's always there. I did hope to become more popular but indeed it lacks stuff like daily rollover, nice formatters, and redeployable configs etc... yet nothing you can't manually do better than log4j :)

Comment: @bestsss - I also remember when `java.util.logging` was new.  It was definitely better than nothing.  However, I got fed up with **having to waste coding and documentation effort** doing things manually.  The **only** advantage that `java.util.logging` has is that you don't need a 3rd party JAR file for logging.  But most non-trivial Java projects involve using lots of 3rd party libraries, so this is pretty much a non-issue.

Comment: Apologies for getting back to you only now; but why to switch to alternative when my app would be a number of times smaller than the whole log library? and also the whole logging was already in place and the only problem was that logger got stuck; I reworked the app (got rid of unnecessary threads) and now everything is running smoothly. Bottomline - I don't know why it was happening but it got solved :)

Comment: @Wojtek - I would conclude that the actual bug was not in the logging at all.  (And your question was a total red herring.)  Rather your application stopped producing any log messages because it had got "stuck" due to some thread-related problem.  I had assumed that you were saying that your application was still doing useful work and the logging had stopped.

Comment: Well, it was - every thread was running fine producing output in different areas (xmpp traffic).

Comment: Whatever.  Now that you've changed it all, you'll never know for sure what the real problem was.